# How do we know that cursor has moved to next line in edittext android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edit text and i want to know if the cursor has moved to the next line or not, if it has moved to next line i want to call a new function. how can i do this?
Is there a way or a function from which i can know that the cursor has moved to the next line?

PS: I am using a text watcher to implement Upper case and lower case functionality

```
scene.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int j, int k) {
                if(flag!=0)
                {
                    flag=1;
                    strcheck = s.toString().charAt(s.length()-1);

                    int line = getCurrentCursorLine(scene);


                    lineno = line;




                    if(strcheck=='\n' && ib1==true){
                        ib22(scene, lineno);

                    }   else if(strcheck=='\n' && ib2==true){

                        ib22(scene, lineno);

                    }   else if(strcheck=='\n' && ib3==true){

                        ib55(scene, lineno);

                    }   else if(strcheck=='\n' && ib4==true){

                        ib55(scene, lineno);

                    }   else if(strcheck=='\n' && ib5==true){

                        ib33(scene, lineno);

                    }   else if(strcheck=='\n' && ib6==true){

                        ib11(scene, lineno);

                    }   else if(strcheck=='\n' && ib7==true){

                        ib22(scene, lineno);

                    }   else if(strcheck=='\n' && ib1==false && ib2==false && ib3==false && ib4==false && ib5==false && ib6==false && ib7==false){

                        ib22(scene, lineno);

                    }



                    //int start = scene.getLayout().getLineStart(lineno);
                    //int end = scene.getLayout().getLineEnd(lineno);
                    //String previous = (start<1 && lineno==0)?"":scene.getText().toString().substring(0, start);


                    if (nowUpper){
                        flag = 0;
                        strcheck = Character.toUpperCase(strcheck);
                        scene.setText(scene.getText().toString().substring(0,scene.length()-1) + strcheck);
                        //scene.setText(previous + scene.getText().toString().substring(start, end).toUpperCase());
                        scene.setSelection(scene.getText().length());
                    }


                    else if (nowLower){
                        strcheck = Character.toLowerCase(strcheck);
                    }

                }
                else{
                    flag=1;
                }
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int i, int j, int k) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to detect that the user has added a newline to the EditText

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459848/833622) for more info.

Comment: I am already using a textwatcher. see the code i have just added, how can i detect a line change now?

Comment: you cannot, TextWatcher does not notify about.selection changes, use SpanWatcher instead

Answer (score 0):

The `TextWatcher` may be what you are looking for.
Further to your usage it does notify you when the user moves the cursor.
Try to check the given position in the `beforeTextChanged()` callback, so that you can react on it, before the text changes it's value.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Example:

```
txtEdit.addTextChangedListener (new TextWatcher() {

          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

          }

          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

          }

          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          }
     });
```

You will get the new position of the cursor within these callbacks, this might be what you want.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

TextWatchers does not tell you about selecrion changes, use a SpanWatcher instead, set it as a span to your Editable text with start == 0, end == Editable.length() and flags == Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE